# Match function not finding data

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code below and for some reason the match function is not returning the row number. The intent of the match is to find the row number in the Contact Table, column ID and use that row number in the index and get the data (which is a date) from Contact Table, Column Last Review. The data flow is like this:

1. A table with data is on one page.
2. A pivot table is made from the data table and the data is re-organized with data from other tables also in the workbook using vlookup functions. The pivot table is only one column.
3. One of these variables, called IDNum, which is found using the name from the pivot table and the corresponding information from the Contact table is used in a match function to find the row on the Contact table.

Now, when the program runs, the match function here does not ever find a match in the IDNum column. If I type in a Match excel function it works fine. That function was this: INDEX(Contact[Last Review],MATCH(B7, Contact[ID],0),0). B7 is the IDNum in the VBA code.

I thought maybe the data in the tables or how I have the variable defined may be an issue, but that would be odd since the in IDNum is the same data originally pulled from the Contact table.

The data on the excel doc is in general format. IDNum is defined as a string in VBA code and it's a global variable. The IDNum variable pulls the correct information.

Are there other ways to check to see if the data in variable IDNum is different from the dataset Match is supposed to be looking in? How can I check to see if the table column in the match function is the correct information? What are some other things I can look at to try and trouble shoot this?

```
Private Function TryGetRevisionDate(ByVal ID As String, ByRef outResult As Date) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        Dim matchRow As Long
        matchRow = .Match(IDNum, Contact.ListColumns("ID").DataBodyRange, 0)

        Dim indexValue As Variant
        indexValue = .Index(Contact.ListColumns("Last Review").DataBodyRange, matchRow)
    End With

    If IsDate(indexValue) Then outResult = indexValue
    TryGetRevisionDate = True

CleanExit:
    Exit Function

CleanFail:
    'lookup failed
    Resume CleanExit
End Function
```

Comment: Remove the On Error line to see what's going on. What is `Contact`?

Comment: Tables are referenced like so `ListObjects("Contact")...`

Comment: What is the formula for the `MATCH` function that does work? What is the value of `ID` when the function runs? Does it match *exactly* with the value of the first parameter of the working `MATCH` function? Help us out here, there's zero information in this entire post that can help a 3rd party that isn't looking at your screen know why this function would consistently return `False`.

Comment: Contact is a table. It's set in the procedure that feeds into this one.

Comment: `Contact` would probably be better off as a `Public Property Get Contact() As ListObject` member in the code-behind of the worksheet that contains this table, with `Set Contact = Me.ListObjects("NameOfTheTable")` for a body. Actually, `Contacts` or even `ContactTable` would be a much better name for it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I'm am going do drive you crazy today. From what I can tell, the value in IDNum and ID are the same. There are no trailing or leading spaces, when I set to two cells equal in excel, it returns true. What other way can I test it? I feel like I'm missing something very fundamental here.

Comment: This question is not answerable in its current form. Please [edit] your working `MATCH` function, including the parameters you're using, then tell us about the value of `ID` when this function is executed. Use breakpoints (F9), the immediate pane (Ctrl+G) with `Debug.Print` statements; use the *Locals* toolwindow - if the `MATCH` function works, then there's no reason that, **given the same data**, this `TryGet` function wouldn't be working. But you can't just give us the listing of the function and say "why is this always returning `False`?" - nobody can know that.

Comment: Also.. no worries, not going crazy yet ;-)

Comment: When I say working match function, I mean I entered a match/index function into an excel cell to see if it worked there. It did. =INDEX(Contact[Last Review],MATCH(B7, Contact[SID],0),0).    B7 in this formula is the IDNum in the VBA Match.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what your *question* needs to contain, along with the value of B7 and that of the `ID` parameter when B7 is passed to it. Basically the `TryGet` function serves no purpose here. That said shouldn't that be `,0))` instead of `,0),0)`?

Comment: The Excel function you pasted into your comment references the table column `SID` while the VBA in the question references the column `ID`.......

Comment: That's a typo. Sorry, I am trying to not put certain variable names on here but I have tripled checked and that variable is correctly named in the code.

Comment: Also, you have the variable in the parameter declaration as `ID` and in the .Match using `IDNum`. I would recommend adding an `Option Explicit` at the top of the code modules.

Comment: @Mistella, This entire code is long and works completely. Option explicit is used to ensure all variables are declared. I added this sub procedure today and for some reason I can't get the Match function to return any number besides 0. For example, when the function above is typed in, the Match function returns 2, but when that IDNum (same IDNum as in B7) is passed through the VBA code 0 is returned.

Comment: @MsAgentM I apologize if my last comment came across wrong. I realize now that I could have worded it differently. I had missed in your question where you had stated that `IDNum` was a global variable, and instead, I had assumed that the `ID` parameter was supposed to be the the `IDNum` variable. Since a lot of coding issues on this site are due to typos, I thought it prudent to mention the `Option Explicit` as the people who are unaware of it find the recommendation helpful.

Comment: No need to apologize. I know in researching my own issues that very, very often typos are the issue. I think my issue here is very simple and fundamental and unfortunately, in my newb-ness, I am unable to properly communicate my issue. Your comment is just you doing your due diligence.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I played around a bit with the code from your question, and it seems to work when both the Table ID and the code ID are strings, or when both are numbers, but not when one is a string and the other a number. Then I get a "Run Time error '1004'".

Comment: @Mistella, I wish I would get an error message... The RevSID variable is defined as a string. The data on the table is in general format but I have tried specifying text and made all data numerical/integer and it still didn't work. I am going forward with a different logic because of time constraints but I'll continue to work on this on my own time simply to sooth bruised pride...

Comment: Fair enough. Just noting that the lack of error message would be due to the error catching you have set up: `On Error GoTo CleanFail`.